# Comparing two versions of programming code with LaTeX

Tags: listings, sourcecode

I'd like to compare two versions of program with vertical line between them.
How can I do this with LaTeX?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way would be to use two `minipage`s and [the `listings` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings):

[image]

While you are at it, you can also add a bit of syntax highlighting, and import an external file which has the source code you want to show:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `filecontents` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) was used here simply to package the [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) into one file.  It is not needed for your actual useage.

---

### Code: Basic

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=c++]
// before refactoring
class A {
  public int f;
  void m (int i) {
     f = i + f;
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill\vrule\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=c++]
// after refactoring
class A {
  private int f;
  void m(int i) {
     setF(i * getF()();
  }

  public int getF() {
    return this.F;
  }

  public void setF(int f) {
    this.f = f;
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

### Code: Fancy

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{before.c}
// before refactoring
class A {
  public int f;
  void m (int i) {
     f = i + f;
  }
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{after.c}
// after refactoring
class A {
  private int f;
  void m(int i) {
     setF(i * getF()();
  }

  public int getF() {
    return this.F;
  }

  public void setF(int f) {
    this.f = f;
  }
}
\end{filecontents*}

\lstdefinestyle{MyStyle}{ %
    language=C++,
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},
    basicstyle=\small,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{red}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \lstinputlisting[style=MyStyle]{before.c}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill\vrule\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \lstinputlisting[style=MyStyle]{after.c}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

use a simple tabular environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings,beramono}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\dimexpr0.4\linewidth-\tabcolsep}% can be up to 0.5\linewidth 
                 | p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep}@{}}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=c++]
// before refactoring
class A {
  public int f;
  void m (int i) {
     f = i + f;
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}
&
\begin{lstlisting}[language=c++]
// after refactoring
class A {
  private int f;
  void m(int i) {
     setF(i * getF()();
  }

  public int getF() {
    return this.F;
  }

  public void setF(int f) {
    this.f = f;
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]